# How to build a typed variadic function from a container?

Tags: haskell, variadic-functions, continuations

Consider the lovely little [HoleyMonoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HoleyMonoid) library, which lets you build typed variadic printf-like functions as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Control.Category
import Data.HoleyMonoid
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)

foo =
    now "hello "
  . later id
  . now ", you are "
  . later show
  . now " years old"

bar = run foo

-- > bar "alice" 42
-- "hello alice, you are 42 years old"

-- > bar 42 "alice"
-- type error
```

Is there any way to examine a container (a list, an AST, etc.) and build such a function based on its contents?

As a toy example, you can picture something like the following:

```
import Data.Monoid

adder = go where
  go [] = now (Sum 0)
  go (x:xs)
    | x == 5    = now 100 . go xs
    | otherwise = later id . go xs

-- hypothetical usage
--
-- > :t run adder [1, 3, 5]
-- Num a => Sum a -> Sum a -> Sum a
--
-- > getSum $ run adder [1, 3, 5] 0 1
-- 101
```

`adder` fails the occurs check, but you can see what I'm shooting for.  The problem seems to be that it's difficult to hold the state of the computation anywhere, as i.e. `now 100` and `later id` are at different types.

Comment: Well, what type is `adder` supposed to be? Apparently you want the type to depend on the length of the list. That'd be a [dependent type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). Haskell is not ([quite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961651/why-not-be-dependently-typed/13241158#13241158)) a dependently-typed language, so this isn't possible. What could work is to decide the type according to the arguments you give, and crash at runtime when this doesn't match the list... but that's not exactly Haskell idiomatic.

Comment: Not with regular lists. With GADT-y lists you can likely achieve something similar e.g. as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25422805/3234959

Comment: @leftaroundabout It may not be idiomatic, but that's essentially what `Text.Printf` does. Apart from the runtime checking this method also has the problem that it cannot handle polymorphic functions like `show`.

Comment: Well, printf has one special application where this particular overloading mechanism is just spot on – if you want to quickly print multiple values of primitive (monomorphic), possible different types, in a single line. If it weren't for the requirement of different types, this would better be implemented with a simple list argument.

Comment: Presently in my real application I'm passing a `Map` of labelled `Dynamic` arguments to a function, where the label indicates to which node of an AST to supply the value.  This works, but is obviously not ideal; in particular the manual wrapping of arguments via `toDyn` is a pain.  I'm not 100% sure if the `printf`-style route is really better, but it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll ignore the HoleyMonoid library.

We need natural numbers:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

A singleton to lift them to the type level:

```
data Natty :: Nat -> * where
    Zy :: Natty Z
    Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (S n)
```

The type of lists of existentials:

```
data Listy (b :: a -> *) :: [a] -> * where
    Nilly :: Listy b '[]
    Consy :: b x -> Listy b xs -> Listy b (x ': xs)
```

Then with

```
type Natties = Listy Natty
```

We can define

```
adder :: Natties ns -> Adder ns
```

where `ns :: [Nat]`. The `Adder` type family is defined like this:

```
type family Adder (ns :: [Nat]) :: * where
    Adder '[]       = Int
    Adder (n ': ns) = If (NatEq n (S (S (S (S (S Z)))))) Int (Int -> Adder ns)
```

I.e. fold a list of `Nat`s, prepending `(Int ->)` for each number in the list, until `5` (in a `Nat` form) is encountered. It actually should be something like

```
if_then_else_ b x y = if b then x else y

type family Adder (ns :: [Nat]) :: * where
    Adder '[]       = Int
    Adder (n ': ns) = 'if_then_else_ (n '== 'fromInt 5) Int (Int -> Adder ns)
```

but GHC throws at me some creepy errors, that I do not want to understand.

The `NatEq` type family is defined in the obvious way:

```
type family NatEq n m :: Bool where
    NatEq  Z     Z    = True
    NatEq  Z    (S m) = False
    NatEq (S n)  Z    = False
    NatEq (S n) (S m) = NatEq n m
```

We need to compare `Natty`s at the value level. Two `Natty`s are equal, iff they indexed by the same number (that's why `Natty` is a singleton):

```
nattyEq :: Natty n -> Natty m -> Booly (NatEq n m)
nattyEq  Zy     Zy    = Truly
nattyEq  Zy    (Sy m) = Falsy
nattyEq (Sy n)  Zy    = Falsy
nattyEq (Sy n) (Sy m) = nattyEq n m
```

Where `Booly` is another singleton:

```
data Booly :: Bool -> * where
    Truly :: Booly True
    Falsy :: Booly False
```

Finally, the definition of `adder`:

```
adder = go 0 where
    go :: Int -> Natties ns -> Adder ns
    go i  Nilly       = 0
    go i (Consy n ns) = case nattyEq n (Sy (Sy (Sy (Sy (Sy Zy))))) of
        Truly -> i + 100
        Falsy -> \a -> go (i + a) ns
```

I.e. sum all arguments, until `5` (in a `Natty` form) is encountered, and add `100`. If there is no `5` in the list, then return `0`.

Tests:

```
list = Consy Zy $ Consy (Sy Zy) $ Consy (Sy (Sy (Sy (Sy (Sy Zy))))) $ Consy Zy $ Nilly

main = do
    print $ adder (Consy Zy $ Consy (Sy Zy) $ Nilly) 3 9 -- 0
    print $ adder list 6 8                               -- 114
    print $ adder (Consy (Sy (Sy Zy)) list) 1 2 3        -- 106
```

The [code](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/stuff/adder.hs).